# Footer at bottom of page insted of screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, footer

My footer has a problem. When load a page it is loaded at bottom of screen insted of bottom of page.
[image: footer bottom of screen insted of bottom of page]
My footer is a simple **div** with css and his parent is **body**.

Here is my css code

```
.footer{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #0063bf;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

P.S.: I use bootstrap, if this help. And in terms of bootstrap i want a navbar-static-bottom, but bootstrap has just fixed-bottom :( So I created my own css class.

Comment: Can you please post your `html` page, so I would try to help you? This can be done, with bootstrap,  without altering or using any css.

Comment: post all css you have for body

Comment: I use CodeIgniter and has some erros in priview
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXRWqq

Comment: I have looked at your pen and I have posted an answer with the explanation why it was not working as you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Does body have `position:relative` ? If not, try adding it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it like this:

```
.footer{
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #0063bf;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This puts it into the document flow - if it's last in the HTML code, it will be displayed as the last element (as long as the other elements also ar in the document flow and not have position absolute or fixed)

Comment: Now footer is on bottom, but if page is to short, it appear above and remain white space under footer until bottom. http://i.imgur.com/4boSsuK.png

Comment: Here is personal css and html http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXRWqq
But I use CodeIgniter and has some errors in preview.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the footer outside the container. This is right if you want are planning to have it fixed at the bottom of the page.

To have the footer on the page end you need to place the footer inside the page container:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
     <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-7 col-md-offset-1'>
                Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
          </div>
          <div class='col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 content-drp'>
               <center>
                 Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
               </center>
          </div>
     </div>
     <div class="footer" style="background:#EEE">
           &copy; <?php echo mdate('%Y');?> Text
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
   footer{
   width:100%;
    background-color: #0063bf;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
     height:60px;
  }
```

```html
<footer><footer>
```